# Automatically adding a month-summery row at the end of each month?

Tags: excel

I'm using an excel sheet to track my working hours. Each row represents a working day and has "date", "time in", "time out", "total working hours", and "daily salary".
I'd like the sheet to automatically create a month summery line every time I write an entry in the next month (i.e if a row with the date 13/3/16 is followed by a row with the date 2/4/16, the second row will be pushed down, and a row with the summery (i.e: total monthly hours, total monthly salary) will be created in between. it should look something like that:
[image]

Is that possible? if so, how do I do it?
Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You should place this code in Sheet Code Module. It worked for me on data organized like your.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ThisSheet As Worksheet
Dim NewRow As Long
Dim OldTotalRange As Range
Dim OldTotalRow As Long

Set ThisSheet = ActiveSheet
'If not single cell is changed, exit sub
If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
'Disable events for prevent recursion
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row <> 1 And Target.value <> "" Then
    If IsDate(Target.value) And IsDate(Target.Offset(-1, 0).value) Then
        If Month(Target.value) <> Month(Target.Offset(-1, 0).value) Then
            With ThisSheet
                NewRow = Target.Row
                On Error Resume Next
                    Set OldTotalRange = .Columns(1).Find(What:="Total", After:=Target, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
                    OldTotalRow = OldTotalRange.Row
'It's for first 'Total' when there isn't 'totals' before.
                If OldTotalRow = 0 Then
                    OldTotalRow = 1
                End If
                    .Rows(NewRow).Insert
                    .Cells(NewRow, 1) = "Total"
                    .Cells(NewRow, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & NewRow - OldTotalRow - 1 & "]C:R[-1]C)"
                    .Cells(NewRow, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & NewRow - OldTotalRow - 1 & "]C:R[-1]C)"
'It's formatting, you can delete it or change
                    .Range(.Cells(NewRow, 1), .Cells(NewRow, 5)).Interior.Color = RGB(196, 215, 155)
                    .Range(.Cells(NewRow, 1), .Cells(NewRow, 5)).Font.Bold = True
            End With
        End If
    End If
End If
Else
Exit Sub
End If
'Enable events
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you explain your solution a little bit.